# Error al asociar un evento a un botón

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quise hacer un ejemplo que vi, pero el JavaScript no me resulta igual. Quisiera saber en qué ando mal, sólo es un botón que hace aparecer un pequeño párrafo.

```css
$(document).on('ready', funcPrincipal);
function funcPrincipal() {
  $('#btnverificar').on('click', funVerificar);
}

function funVerificar() {
  $('#respuesta').text('fnciona bien');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="prueba.CSS">
  <title>Prubea</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="txtUser">
  <input type="button" value="aceptar" id="btnverificar">
  <p id="respuesta"></p>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="hola.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probablemente tengas una línea en rojo en la consola que diga `GET https://tuweb.bla/jquery-3.2.1.min.js `.. ¿Podrías agregar esta información en tu pregunta? Siempre se deberían agregar todos los errores que aparecen en la consola

Comment: no sale ningún error en consola ahahaahahh, pense que lo estaba llamando mal,pero llame un css igual y si aparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas (según entiendo) es agregar al botón un evento click. Para lograr esto solo usamos la siguiente linea de cogido: **$(id).click(function);** Como tu script está agregado al final de tu estructura HTML no es necesario usar el .on(ready).Porque para cuando se ejecute tu script Toda la estructura html referenciada ya existe y podrá ejecutarse.

```js
$('#btnverificar').click(funVerificar);

function funVerificar() {
  debugger;
  $('#respuesta').text('funciona bien');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script-->
  <title>Prubea</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="txtUser">
  <input type="button" value="aceptar" id="btnverificar">
  <p id="respuesta"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Espero que te sirva. 
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Probé el código y me funciona bien, no debes estar cargando bien el archivo `hola.js`. Verifica que efectivamente esté en la misma carpeta que tu página, al igual que el archivo jQuery. También puedes verificar en la consola si tienes algún error.

Para jQuery, si no te interesa descargarlo, otra alternativa es incluirlo directamente desde un CDN en la web. En tu código, quedaría:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: perdón no se repite, ahora me deja comentar, la verdad es que no se si esta cargando o no el jquery, por eso iba a modo de pregunta.

Comment: Gracias Mariano, edite la respuesta para que se vea como tal y no como un comentario.

Comment: ningun error en la consola xd